# If $X(t)$ is a matrix valued path in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, then $X(t)^{-1}$ is also.

Tags: group-theory, continuity

Suppose there is a continuous path $X:[0,1] \rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ from $I$ to $A$.  I need help showing that $X(t)^{-1}$ is continuous.  This shows that there is a continuous path from $I$ to $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Do you have the fact that for $G=GL_n({\mathbb R})$, the inverse map $\nu:G\to G$ is continuous?

Comment: Nope.  I should probably study continuity and this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cramer's rule shows how to compute the inverse of a matrix using the reciprocal of the determinant and matrices with entries that are polynomial functions of the variables.  Since the determinant is non-zero, this will be a continuous function.

Once you have that inversion is a continuous function for invertible matrices, it follows that connected paths are mapped to connected paths.